# Retrieving data from mysql using radiobutton

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have 2 comboboxes for zone and subzone,for zone combobox name zone and for subzone combobox name is subzone and also I have 1 radio button for zone.The problem is when I select zone I want to retrieve all the subzones based on zone using radio button for zone I should display the data using jsp.

I tried the following code:

```
    if(r1.equals("Zone"))
    {
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Meter_List where Zone='"+getZoneName+"' and  Subzone='"+subzonelist+"'");
    flag="false";
    }
Here r1 is radio button name.

    if(flag.equals("false"))
{
%><table style="" width="900px" align="center" border="1"cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">

<th>Meter ID</th>
<th>Consumer ID</th>
<th>Consumer Name</th>
<th>Reading</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Sub Zone</th>
<th>Zone</th>
<%
while(rs.next())
{
%>
<tr><font size="4"><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%></font></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Consumername")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("LastReading")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getDate("Date")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getTime("Time")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Status")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Zone")%></td></tr>
<%
}

}
```

Comment: Did you write any code to iterate the result set and display in subzone?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . the following code is to display the data

Comment: if(flag.equals("false"))
{
%><table style="" width="900px" align="center" border="1"cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">

<th>Meter ID</th>
<th>Consumer ID</th>
<th>Consumer Name</th>
<th>Reading</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Sub Zone</th>
<th>Zone</th>

Comment: <%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%></font></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Consumername")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("LastReading")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getDate("Date")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getTime("Time")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Status")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Zone")%></td></tr>

Comment: Please put the code in your question itself. Also does your header come?

Comment: Thanks for you reply i have posted my remaining code please help me to solve this

Comment: Good. Cleanup the comments(delete them). Now my original question: is your subzone header displayed? What exactly is the issue in your code/expected behavior?

Comment: Now my problem is i am selecting the zone radiobutton it means i have only one radio button for zone and subzone comboboxes,when i select the zone combo box i am getting all the subzones based on zone selected,but i am unable to get the data based on zone and zubzone from mysql table.